# Rails-Has_many relationships not saving user or group id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and Group model that I bind with an Assignments model. A user has_many groups and a group has_many users. However, when I create a new group, when I do `Group.last.users.count` the output is 0 or ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []. Do I need to change an aspect of my simple_form? Did I not build the middleman model correctly to bind users and groups? I would like it so that when a user creates a group, the group_ids are in the array when doing `User.last.groups`, etc. When I had it as User has_many groups and a Group belongs_to user, the group ids would be tied to a user. But since switching to has_many for both models and introducing the Assignments model, this is no longer the case.

Group Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true   

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  has_many :posts
  has_many :attachments
  has_secure_token

end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :groups, through: :assignments
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
 ...
```

Assignment Model

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Groups Controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    @group = current_user.groups.build
end

def create
    @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)
    @group.user_id = current_user.id
    if @group.save
        redirect_to groups_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

  def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:group_name, :description, :user_id)
  end

end
```

Group new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :group_name %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'd urge you to try it in rails console to see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: Group `has_many` users but has `user_id` property? This doesn't seem right

Comment: This is what I have  for Group.last.users ` => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> ` and for User.last.groups ` => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

I guess the `build` method seems not saving the joiner model you can use `new`. There is an issue [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-5586751):

As there is many-to-many relation between `Group` and `User`. Thus there is no need for `user_id` in group. Thus the validation is unnecessary. And it causes the problem with my first approach. In model comment the validation. `# validates :user_id, presence: true`

```
def create
    @group = current_user.groups.new(group_params)
    # @group.user_id = current_user.id // this line is unnecessary
    if @group.save
        redirect_to groups_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Or, (I'll not suggest it as it is not a good approach)

```
def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
        current_user.groups << @group
        redirect_to groups_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Comment: tried new and still no luck. Am I missing something in my form_for?

Comment: @user3318660, what are the parameters you got in `group_params`? Edited answer.

Comment: This is what I have `def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:group_name, :description, :user_id)
 end`

Comment: @user3318660, did you checked the updated answer? Also, when you submitted your `form` for creating a new group, what is written in your console log?

Comment: `INSERT INTO "groups" ("group_name", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "token") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["group_name", "e"], ["description", "e"], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-06-16 08:27:18.449820"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-16 08:27:18.449820"], ["token", "2xN34NPvRjpPxGhSqNXS1UiN"]]`

Comment: @user3318660, did you delete the `validation` from the `group.rb` file? And also which approach is rendering to `:new`?

Comment: Oh that was the problem. I removed the validations so now your second solution worked the `def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
        current_user.groups << @group
        redirect_to groups_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114828/discussion-between-user3318660-and-emu).